# Showing dialog from run() method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pop up dialog from run method it gives me exception that Looper.prepare not called, when I call the same method i dont get any exception but there is no pop up dialog shown on the console. As I have used handler in this way ,

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        showDialog(DIALOG1_KEY);
        // process incoming messages here
    }
};
```

I am not getting any exception again but still no luck can any body tell me where I am doing things wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the code snippet you've provided, but I think you're using the Handler incorrectly.

What you need to do is initialize a new `Handler` object on them main thread, for example by defining it as a field variable.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then create a new `Runnable` that includes the instructions you want to execute on the GUI thread (but which will be called from your background thread's `run` method).

```
private Runnable runOnGUI = new Runnable() {
  private void run() {
    showDialog(DIALOG1_KEY);
  }
};
```

Then within your run method you need use the handler object to post your `runOnGUI` method on the GUI thread.

```
private Runnable runInBackground = new Runnable() {
  private void run() {
    handler.post(runOnGUI);
    // Do processing
  }
};
```

Comment: You can also use the runOnUiThread(Runnable) method, available since Android 1.1 - it does exactly the same thing but with about 1 less line of code.